# In Linear regression is it possible to have same sign coefficients for dummies coming from the same variable?

Tags: regression, linear-model, scikit-learn

So I have a `categorical variable` color which can take the values white, black, red.

I created `dummy variables` for each of those colors and the related `coefficients` for all of those dummy variables is `negative`.

I wonder how is this possible, what would be the baseline here?

EDIT: y variable is `price`, using `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` coupled with `pandas.get_dummies`

Comment: what is your y variable? what code/data are you using?

Comment: See edit Im using sklearn and pandas the y variable is price.

Answer (score 1):

This is no problem. Intuitively, if you include all three categories, their coefficients "absorb" the intercept, which might be negative.

Comment: The intercept is positive, and all the coefficients are negative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the intercept is the base level, and the coefficient of each color is relative to that base level. Here is a short example in R. relevel allow to decide which level of the factor will be used as the base line.

```
library('dplyr')

> col <- factor(sample(c('red', 'blue', 'white'), n, replace = TRUE))
> 
> y <- case_when(col == 'red' ~ 30, 
+                col == 'blue' ~ 80, 
+                col == 'white' ~ 115) + rnorm(n, 0, 5)
> 
> 
> col <- relevel(col, 'red')
> lm(y ~ col) ### coefficients will be positive  

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ col)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      colblue     colwhite  
      29.84        50.02        86.14  

> 
> col <- relevel(col, 'blue')
> lm(y ~ col) ### coefficients will be positive and negative 

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ col)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       colred     colwhite  
      79.86       -50.02        36.12  

> 
> col <- relevel(col, 'white')
> lm(y ~ col) ### coefficients will be negative

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ col)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      colblue       colred  
     115.98       -36.12       -86.14
```

Example when all the coefficients are negative (notice there is no intercept)

```
> y <- case_when(col == 'red'   ~ -30, 
+                col == 'blue'  ~ -80, 
+                col == 'white' ~ -115) + rnorm(n, 0, 5)
> 
> lm(y ~ 0 + col) ### coefficients will be negative

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + col)

Coefficients:
colwhite   colblue    colred  
 -115.75    -80.30    -30.24
```

Comment: But in this case you have one of the levels as the baseline, in my case all the levels have negative coefficients.

Comment: If you have an intercept in the model, then one of the factors level is absorbed by it (notice in the example that the intercept value is similar to that of the level). Ill add an example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but in my particular case, in sklearn implementation in Python, there is an intercept which is positive, and at the same time there is a  coefficient for each of the variables, which are all negative.